# Socket.io - How to create C# object from JSON object Unity?

Tags: javascript, socket.io, backend

I coded little on the server-side. That's what I have at the moment at the server-side.

```
var player = {
    x: 25,
    y: 10,
    z: 22
}

socket.emit('spawn', {player.x});
```

But I don't know how to create C# object from this JSON object on my client side.

I need C# object to convert it to string later

Thanks in advance

Comment: `socket.emit('spawn', player.x);` does not works?

Comment: No. By googling I knew that sending in JSON is ok. So how to create C# object from JSON on my client side

Comment: Isn't this more of a C# question then? Since you already have the JSON on your C# client?

Comment: if you create a c# object with the same properties of the JSON you're sending, it should recognize.